# Why do people in __init__.py files use: "import same_name as same_name"

Tags: python, python-import, init

I saw this in the fastapi repository:

```
from .api_key import APIKeyCookie as APIKeyCookie
```

I am wondering what is the reason of importing something and renaming it to its same name.

Example source:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/security/__init__.py

I would personally expect the code like this:

```
from .api_key import APIKeyCookie
```

While it looks like this:

```
from .api_key import APIKeyCookie as APIKeyCookie
```

Comment: Note, its much better to use `__all__ = ["APIKeyCookie"]` than the `from y import x as x` trick. The trick is used to silence static analyzers about importing variables not declared by the module. `__all__` lets you be much more clear about what you actually want to expose from the `__init__.py` file, rather than having all references imported be potentially valid. This makes life a lot simpler, especially if you have to do anything more complex in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You opened a whole new "\_\_all\_\_" world for me!